# Input field wrapping using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm new to the flexbox, and I tried to create an input form like in the picture below.
First, two fields are supposed to be 50% of the width of div, other two are 100% width. In the mobile view, they are supposed to stack on each other.
Can I use "width" and "height" attributes on textarea?

[image]

```css
.form{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.input-flex{
  max-width: 600px;

}

input, textarea{
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 2%;
  background-color: darkgray;
  margin-right: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  flex:1 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="input-flex">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name*"/>       
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail*"/>
    <input type="tel" name="number" placeholder="Phone number*"/>
    <textarea cols="55" rows="15" placeholder="Questions"></textarea>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: On a side note: Placeholder is not a substitute for a label. You should really look into semantic HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that you defined `.form` as the flex parent, even though your elements were inside `.input-flex` - so I just copied the style to this element.

Regarding your question: by using a dedicated class, you can specify which elements should have 100% width.

Other than that, I changed the `margin` to be constant all around the elements, so the result better matches the design.

```css
.form {
  width: 100%;
}

.input-flex {
  max-width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

input,
textarea {
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 2%;
  background-color: darkgray;
  margin: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">
  <div class="input-flex">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name*" />
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail*" />
    <input type="tel" class="full-width" name="number" placeholder="Phone number*" />
    <textarea cols="55" rows="15" class="full-width" placeholder="Questions"></textarea>
  </div>
</div>
```